# How to join two entities through two secondary tables in hibernate jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entities

i would need your kind help.

I have entities for table_action and table_list. I want to have in table_action entity a list of table_list elements. I cannot change the database model and I have to use hibernate.[image: db_model]
You can see the connections on the screenshot below.

What I have for now doesn`t work:

```
     TableAction.java :

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "table_action2list", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "OBJID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "list_objid", referencedColumnName = "objid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "list_type", referencedColumnName = "list_type", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "list_kind", referencedColumnName = "list_kind", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
private Set<TableList> tableList = new HashSet<TableList>();
```

I don`t know how to join table_action2plan.

This is the sql which works.

```
    select rl.* from table_list rljoin table_action2list arc on arc.LIST_OBJID = rl.OBJID and arc.LIST_KIND = rl.LIST_KIND and arc.LIST_TYPE = rl.LIST_TYPE join table_action2plan ac on ac.OBJID = arc.action2plan_objid join table_action ta on ta.OBJID = ac.ACTION_OBJID ;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that table_action2plan and table_action2list are secondary tables but I can also create entities if this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it turned out that I cannot have in table_action entity a list of table_list since there is no such a relation in TableAction. The problem was solved by changing the db structure so that there is only one connecting table between the entities. Then it worked as usual with a JoinTable annotation.